# How to transform a logical constraint with integer variables?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, integer-programming, logical-constraints

Consider the binary variables $x_1, x_2 \in \{0,1\}$ and the integer variable $y \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $0 \leq y \leq 3$.

I'd like to formulate the following logical constraint:

$$
x_1 = 1 \wedge y \geq 2 \implies x_2 = 1
$$

and I don't have access to commercial solvers or modelling frameworks. Any ideas?

Comment: It may be: 1) $x_1 \leq x_2$, $\quad$ 2) $y-2+\epsilon \leq (M+\epsilon)x_2$ $\quad$ with $M\leq1$.

Comment: @A.Omidi Your 1) is too strong.  For example, it mistakenly cuts off the feasible solution $(x_1,x_2,y)=(1,0,0)$.

Comment: @RobPratt, Dear Rob, sorry for the delay and thanks for comment. Would you please say, 1) how (1,0,0) may be a feasible one? 2) Another approach I would like to try is by substituting $y \geq 2$ with an indicator constraint. If $z =1 \rightarrow y \geq 2$. Now, the original expression would be $x_1 = 1 \land  z=1 \implies x_2 = 1$. The final result would be something like, ($x_1 + z - x_2 \leq 1$), ($y \geq 2-M(1-z)$),($y-2+\epsilon \leq (M+\epsilon)x_2$). Please, may I have your comments?

Comment: @A.Omidi For $(1,0,0)$, the conditional $x_1 =1\land y\ge 2$ is false, so the proposition is true no matter what the value of the consequent. For your indicator constraint approach, you need the converse instead $y\ge 2\implies z=1$, equivalently, its contrapositive $z=0\implies y\le 1$.

Comment: @RobPratt, Thanks for the clarification.  For the second part, I will update that and back to you. 

Comment: @RobPratt, based on your hint, the constraints would be ($-x_1+x_2+z \geq 0$), ($y+Mz \leq 3$), with $M=2$. Would you please, say your insight about that?

Comment: @A.Omidi you have changed your original interpretation of the two values of $z$, but your new formulation is still correct.  Your big-M constraint enforces $y\ge 2\implies \lnot z$, and your first constraint enforces $(x_1 \land \lnot z) \implies x_2$.

Comment: @RobPratt, thank you so much. Could you please, may I add this as an answer?

Comment: @A.Omidi glad to help. Yes, please post your approach as another answer, and I’ll upvote it. I guess you are asking my permission because I helped, and that is fine with me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can derive the desired linear constraint by rewriting in conjunctive normal form and rearranging to an equivalent implication:
$$
(x_1 \land (y\ge 2)) \implies x_2 \\
\lnot (x_1 \land (y\ge 2)) \lor x_2 \\
\lnot x_1 \lor (y\le 1) \lor x_2 \\
\lnot x_1 \lor x_2 \lor (y\le 1) \\
\lnot (x_1 \land \lnot x_2) \lor (y\le 1) \\ 
(x_1 \land \lnot x_2) \implies (y\le 1) \\
(x_1 \land \lnot x_2) \implies (2\le 3-y) \\
2(x_1 + (1 - x_2) - 1) \le 3-y \\
2(x_1 - x_2) + y \le 3
$$
You can alternatively view this as a big-M constraint arising from the implication $x_1-x_2=1 \implies y \le 1$.

Answer (score 7):

The range of values of the variable $y$ is quite small, so you could use the binary representation $y = b_0 + 2b_1$ with two binary variables $b_0$ and $b_1$ instead of the integer variable $y$.

Then your logical constraint is equivalent to

$$
x_1 = 1 \wedge b_1 = 1 \implies x_2 = 1,
$$

which can be modelled by

$$
x_1 + b_1 \leq 1 + x_2.
$$

Comment: Multiplying by $2$ and adding $b_0$ would then yield $2(x_1-x_2)+y \le 2+b_0 \le 3$, avoiding the additional binary variables.

Comment: @RobPratt Good catch. PS: Your answer is definitely more elegant (+1) than mine.

Comment: Thanks.  I gave you a +1 as well.  It is good to have a variety of approaches, and your formulation is tighter.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach I was trying to do, also based on @RobPratt hints, would be by substituting $y \geq 2$ as an indicator constraint and changing the original logical expression into:

$$ \{x_1 = 1 \wedge y \geq 2 \implies x_2 = 1\}  \rightarrow \{x_1 = 1 \land  \lnot z\implies x_2 = 1\}$$
$$\lnot x_1 \lor  z \lor x_2$$
$$(1-x_1) +  z + x_2 \geq 1$$
$$-x_1 + x_2 + z \geq 0$$

For the second part we need to add:
$$y + Mz \leq 3$$
with $M=2$ to enforce $y\ge 2\implies \lnot z$.